# Determine all semidirect product of $(\mathbb{Z}_4,+)$ by $C_2 = \langle a \rangle$

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

Determine all semidirect product of $(\mathbb{Z}_4,+)$ by $C_2 = \langle a \rangle$.

**My proof:** We have $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_4,+) = \{ \sigma_1,\sigma_3\}$. Define $\theta \colon C_2 \rightarrow \text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_4,+)$. There are two group isomorphisms, so there are two semidirect product.

Comment: What is $\sigma_1$? What is $\sigma_3$? What is $\theta$?  There are two group isomorphisms between what groups? Are these semidirect products isomorphic?If not, are they something you can recognize? You should say a lot more for a question asking you to **determine** those groups.

Comment: there are two *homomorphisms* $C_2 \to \operatorname{Aut}(C_4)$, but only one is an *isomorphism.*

Comment: $\sigma_1,\sigma_3$ are permutations

Comment: @Minh What permutations precisely? The point I am trying to make is that you should be much clearer and precise than you are being at the moment, since you need to show your instructor, in your solutions, that you understand the material, and are not simply copying random symbols from the book or your notes. (I don't know how to state this without sounding too blunt, but I hope you understand my point)

Comment: That’s all my opinion based on some theorems that I have studied. I knew it was sparsely, so I asked for the clearly proof.